Extract certain keys from interface if meet certain condition
I have an interface like this:
interface A {
  a: number;
  b: string:
  c: () => void;
  d: boolean;
  e: {}
}

How can I construct a new interface that only includes the keys that are of type number or string or boolean? so I can end up with:
interface B {
  a: number;
  b: string:
  d: boolean;
}

